# IMU device - How to obtain horizontal rotation angle by calculating euler angle when device is vertical

Tags: arduino, rotation, imu

I read some information about rotation method such as euler angle and quaternion, commonly the imu device z axix is pointing up, and around this axis angle  of rotation is yaw that is i need device direction data, but not i must put the device in the pocket, then z axis(like follow picture) will be pointing forward so how can i get the device absolute direction Relative to the north horizon angle when device is rotate?
[coordinate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdFpI.png)

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Without further info your image just shows 3 arrows and doesn't help at all.
Your question is way too broad. Please read [ask] and improve it. What kind of IMU are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

For absolute movement and orientation measurement you will need at least a second sensor for an absolute reference(like magneto meter allows only slow movement) or start from an fixed orientation (Accuracy decay over time). This would require calibration and a lot of math to work.

What you need the Bosch BNO055. It has an I2C interface and integrates a triaxial 14-bit accelerometer, a triaxial 16-bit gyroscope with a range of ±2000 degrees per second,  a  triaxial  geomagnetic  sensor and a microcontroller to integrate the sensor data and give you absolute movement and orientation data. See [here](https://www.bosch-sensortec.com/bst/products/all_products/bno055)

Comment: thanks your answer, so if when this sensor any rotate that can  stable output horizon angle the north?

Comment: @Haseo: Absolute Orientation (Euler Vector, 100Hz) - Three axis orientation data based on a 360° sphere    AND 
Absolute Orientation (Quaterion, 100Hz) - Four point quaternion output for more accurate data manipulation